How to log FILTER_PARAMS in SQL query within Cube.js?
I'm working with Cube.js and need to log the values of FILTER_PARAMS within an SQL query to verify the parameters passed dynamically to my cube module. I've tried using console.log directly in the sql function, but it throws a TypeError: evaluatedSql.match is not a function error.
cube(`unmapped_devices`, {
  sql: `
    SELECT 
      COUNT(sgm.device_id) as unmappeddevices
    FROM 
      sensor_group_mapping sgm
    WHERE 
      sgm.created_by = ${FILTER_PARAMS.unmapped_devices.casdoorUsername}
  `,
  measures: {
    unmappedDevices: {
      sql: `unmappeddevices`,
      type: `number`
    }
  }
});


I've also tried accessing FILTER_PARAMS in the sql function as follows:
sql: ({ filters }) => {
  console.log("casdoorUsername:", filters.unmapped_devices?.casdoorUsername?.values?.[0]);
  return `
    SELECT ...
  `;
}


What is the best way to log or check the value of FILTER_PARAMS (or other dynamic parameters) inside Cube.js queries for debugging purposes? Is there a recommended method or workaround to inspect these parameters without encountering TypeError?

In logs, I can see the raw sql query right after a line "Executing SQL: fc23688f-c5f7-4326-bd0c-404bac41b0d8-span-1". Is is not your case too?
